# Acessing a QC Structure from a Cocoa Application

Tags: cocoa, arrays, quartz-composer

is there a way of acessing a structure from a Cocoa app? I am able to set integers and Strings using the QCView setvalue:forkey method but when i try to access a structure i run into errors. Basicly what i want to do is to pass a byte array into a Quartz composition.

greetings

matthias

Answer (score 2):

To provide a structure to a composition, feed an NSDictionary or an NSArray to `-setValue:forKey:`.

For example, if you're starting with the Xcode "Quartz Composer Application" template, you could add the following code into AppController's `-changeColorToBlue:` method:

```
[qcView setValue:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"value1",@"key1",@"value2",@"key2",nil] forInputKey:@"Structure"];
```

or

```
[qcView setValue:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"a",@"b",nil] forInputKey:@"Structure"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using Swift 3.1:

```
// for array
qcView.setValue(["Obj1", "Obj2"], forInputKey: "Structure")

// for dictionary
qcView.setValue(["key1":"val1", "key2":"val2"], forInputKey: "Structure")
```